# rotate element of array in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

I wanted to rotate element of array in shell script

```
Array=(11 22 33 44 55)
```

i tried this

```
Array[0]=${Array[$3]}
```

but it is not working, i'm getting array as it was declared.Why?

Finally i got it working as

```
j=0
k=3
Array[$j]=${Array[$k]}
```

But question is why can't we pass index directly as i did previously?

Comment: I think you are looking for "shift"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ITYM:

```
Array=(11 22 33 44 55)
Array[0]=${Array[3]}   # "3", not "$3"
```

Which would have resulted in:

```
Array=(44 22 33 44 55)
```

`$3` expands to the third positional argument (argument to the shell script), if it's empty (as it usually is in an interactive shell), then `${array[$3]}` is the same as `${array[0]}` or `$array`.

If you wanted to achieve:

```
Array=(55 11 22 33 44)
```

You'd need to do:

```
Array=("${Array[4]}" "${Array[@]:0:4}")
```

Or more generally:

```
Array=("${Array[@]: -1}" "${Array[@]:0:${#Array[@]}-1}")
```

With `zsh`, you could  also do:

```
Array[1,0]=$Array[-1] # insert the last element at the beginning
Array[-1]=()          # remove the last element
```

or:

```
Array=("$Array[-1]" "${(@)Array[1,-2]}")
```

With `yash`:

```
array -i Array 0 "${Array[-1]}"
array -d Array -1
```

With `fish` (assuming the Array has at least 2 elements):

```
set Array 11 22 33 44 55
set Array $Array[-1 1..-2]
```

Comment: In bash-4.2, more generally (and less legibly): `Array=("${Array[-1]}" "${Array[@]:0:${#Array[@]}-1}")`

Comment: @mr.spuratic, good idea, I've added a bash3+ variant of that.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas 'Array[0]=${Array[3]}' wasn't working, i needed to use 'Array[$j]=${Array[$k]}' (variable in place of index), why so?

And yes, i wanted to get output as
'Array=(11 22 33 44 55)'
'Array=(55 11 22 33 44)'
'Array=(44 55 11 22 33)' So on

Comment: @AKASH. Try `Array[0]=${Array[3]}` again. It should work. You had `Array[0]=${Array[$3]}` (note the extra `$`) in your question which is a no-op.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, it is working, thank you